# ArcMap layout graphics

Tags: arcgis-10.0, layouts, graphics

When I try to copy graphics and text between .mxd documents, size of the elements (width, height, font size) change randomly. Anyone know how to transfer LayoutElements between .mxd without any distruptions?

Comment: Use ArcMap Templates (.mxt) should preserve graphics http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s90000002w000000.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "Zoom Whole Page" button in layout view on both map documents before you copy / paste.

[image]

This will make all elements in the .mxd the same size.  By default when you paste elements into another map document they should be in the same exact position as they are in the original mxd.

Answer (score 0):

mxt were only until 9.3. You can still use them in 10, but you can also just change the layout to any other mxd, it doesn't have to be a specific template file.
However, do not bother playing around with your legend or any other elements until you change your layout - as these elements will all go back to the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

To copy/paste graphics between .mxd documents you need to set the layout zoomfactor and page size to the same values in both .mxd documents.

When using the same page size in both documents the answer of Roy to use the "Zoom Whole Page" button in layout view on both map documents before you copy/paste is perfectly valid. I found no good work-around for copying graphics between different page sizes other than setting both layouts to the same page size, than copy/paste the graphics and than setting back the page size.